# Why does my dictionary not create the second key?

Tags: python-3.x

So i have 2 dictionaries. One consisting of the number of players and another to record score.

```py
game = {A:[1,2,3,4] B:[2,3,4,5]}
Points = {}
for player in game:
    if Points == {}:
        Points[player] = 0
```

Basically what i'm trying to do populate the points dictionary with 0 points first which will be later used as reference to showcase the number of points. I'm using a while loop so the Points is suppose to come back populated with positive numbers the second time onwards. This problem is only for the first time. The problem i'm having is that it seems to only create the Key A and not B. As such i am getting a KeyError

Answer (score 0):

```
if oldPoints == {}:
        for player in game:
            oldPoints[player] = 0
```

Comment: It isn't clear how this answers the question -- there is no `oldPoints` in the original code.  Perhaps some prose to add context would help?  (I do realize this is a self-answer).